# Return new Page does not work as expected in Lightning (Salesforce1)

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem in a Salesforce1 app. Basically app lets you check-in in an account with Salesforce1 app. By check-in it creates a event tied to this account and redirects to the event page. Problem is while redirecting it uses salesforce web link style. It redirects from emea.lightning.force.com/... to emea.salesforce.com/... and in this page we are not able to do any changes.

Code for creating event and redirecting to event page:

```
 myNewEvent.WhatId = mkn.Id;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
    myNewEvent.StartDateTime = dt.addHours(2);
    myNewEvent.Subject = 'Check-in ' + myNewEvent.StartDateTime;
    myNewEvent.EndDateTime = myNewEvent.StartDateTime.addMinutes(1);
    myNewEvent.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    myNewEvent.Location = String.valueOf(mkn.Location__Latitude__s) + ' ' + String.valueOf(mkn.Location__Longitude__s);
    myNewEvent.EventCurrentLocation__c = latpg + ' ' + lonpg;
    insert myNewEvent;
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' + myNewEvent.Id);
    pr.GetParameters().Put('message', 'Event added successfully');
    pr.setRedirect(True);
    return pr;
```

This check-in page (basically a map with markers on it) throws this error on javascript console: "Refused to connect to 'https://emea.salesforce.com/javascript/source?lastMod=1418031882000&fileName=CanvasRendering.js.map&projectPath=canvas' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'"."

Also when returning to event page javascript console gives this error: "AuraAlohaFrameNavigator.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin 'undefined' in a call to 'postMessage'."

Any help on this would be appreciated since there is not much document on lightning and I'm not really familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Salesforce's [documentation on navigation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm). I believe you will have to use something like:

```
var warehouseNavUrl = 'sforce.one.navigateToSObject(\'' + event.Id + '\')';
//'<a href="javascript:' + warehouseNavUrl + '">'
```